# How to open and capture camera picture in Black and white mode using Camera.Parameter in android

Tags: java, android, api, camera, mono

Hi I have different requirement. I want to open camera from android device which in black and white mode. I tried image color filter on ImageView but that's not suits. When i am writing that image in file as PDF the original color image has written in file. so instead color filter i wish to take picture in black and white mode.I searched and found the camera.parameter api but i don't know where to use it, when i tried that with Intent i am getting can't connect to the camera error message. I want to open camera in black and white mode and take pictures. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Camera Parameter api is when you are creating your own activity with camera mode and not using default camera application. You cannot start the camera in B&W mode using intents.